# How to update a graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using Panda and matplotlib to draw graphs in Python.
I would like a live updating gaph. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
import numpy as np
import MySQLdb
import pandas

def animate():

    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="sentiment_index", use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")
    c = conn.cursor()
    query = """ SELECT t_date , score FROM mytable where t_date BETWEEN Date_SUB(NOW(), Interval 2 DAY) AND NOW()"""
    c.execute(query)
    rows=c.fetchall()
    df = pandas.read_sql(query, conn, index_col=['t_date'])

    df.plot()
    plt.show()

animate()
```

I thought about using FuncAnimation but didn't get the right result. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is a bit light on explanation of how to use
FuncAnimation. However, there are [examples in the
gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/index.html) and blog
tutorials, such as [Jake Vanderplas's](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) and [Sam Dolan's PDF](http://sam-dolan.staff.shef.ac.uk/mas212/lectures/l5.pdf).

This example from Jake Vanderplas's tutorial is perhaps the "Hello World" of
matplotlib animation:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def init():
    return [line]

def animate(i, ax, line):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N) + i/(N*2)
    ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
    line.set_data(x, np.sin(x))
    return [line]

N = 100
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [])
ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=0, frames=int(4*np.pi*N), 
    repeat=True, blit=True, fargs=[ax, line])
plt.show()
```

Change various values or lines of code and see what happens. See what happens if
you change `return [line]` to something else.  If you study and play with these
examples, you can learn how the pieces fit together.

Once you understand this example, you should be able to modify it to fit your
goal.

If you have trouble, post your code and describe what error message or
misbehavior you see.

Some tips:

- Since animation requires calling `line.set_data`, I don't think you
  can use Pandas' `df.plot()`. In fact, I'm not sure if the Pandas DataFrame is
  useful here. You might be better off sucking the data into lists or NumPy arrays
  and passing those to `line.set` as above, without getting Pandas involved.
- Opening a connection to the database should be done once. `animate` gets
  called many times. So it is better to define `conn` and `c` and `query` -- anything that does not change with each call to `animate` -- 
  outside of `animate`, and pass them back as arguments to `animate` via the
  `fargs` parameter.